Histogram with bar width not proportional to bar range
Using Matplotlib, I want to display a heavily long-tailed distribution, such as the one in the attached picture. Obviously, this figure is not very readable. What I want to achieve is as follows:

get a histogram with 4 bars of equal width
the ranges of the bars must be '0', '1-5', '6-25', '26-125'
each bar has its range as a label under the bar

How can I achieve this? I keep getting stuck because Matplotlib makes the bars with a smaller range (e.g. '0') incredibly narrow.

The attached picture was generated with the following code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# fill each of the ranges with 100 elements
data = [0] * 100 + list(range(1,6)) * 20 + list(range(6,26)) * 5 + list(range(26, 125))

# this generates the attached picture
plt.hist(data, bins=max(data)+1)


@jonrsharpe: may I ask why the title was edited? Isn't it useful for people to know that I am looking for matplotlib solutions? Just asking to get better insight into how to ask questions on SO

https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

An artificial solution to this problem can be achieved as follows:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# fill each of the ranges with 100 elements
data = [0] * 100 + list(range(1,6)) * 20 + list(range(6,26)) * 5 + list(range(26, 125))

# compute the bar heights
bar0 = sum(d==0 for d in data)
bar1_5 = sum(1 <= d <= 5 for d in data)
bar6_25 = sum(6 <= d <= 25 for d in data)
bar26_ = sum(26 <= d for d in data)

# plot the histogram
bars = ['0', '1-5', '6-25', '26-125']
heights = [bar0, bar1_5, bar6_25, bar26_]
plt.bar(bars, heights)
plt.show()

This gives the following result:

